# Setting up ssh server on an embedded arm machine

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, embedded, embedded-linux

I have an Arndale board and an x86 desktop machine, both running Linux (Ubuntu on ARM and Debian on desktop, I think). The machines are connected with a straight ethernet cable; it shows up as "eth1" on the desktop and "eth0" on the ARM machine. I want to have the ARM machine run an ssh server, so that most of the development can happen on the desktop machine. How do I configure the network interfaces and ssh to accomplish this? I already have openssh services running on both machines.

This is what I tried (it's probably silly and wrong): on the desktop machine I added these lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.168.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and then executed `ifup eth1`. These are the output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:03:0f:56  
          inet addr:192.168.168.1  Bcast:192.168.168.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4cff:fe03:f56/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)
```

I set the address of eth0 on the ARM machine likewise as "192.168.168.0". I then tried to ping the ARM board (192.168.168.0) from the host machine, and nothing happens. I tried to `arp` the ARM board's MAC address, and it doesn't work either. What should I do? Have I got something mixed up or mistaken?

Thanks

Comment: The very first you should always do is: ping ;) If that is working, you can assume the machines "see" each other. After that, probably you need to deal with those config files for ssh daemon. Not fluent in that aspect but there are settings like "deny root access"...

Comment: @user2225104 oh, thanks for that. I've actually been thinking about ways to test whether there's a connection at all. ping result included.

Comment: You pinged your PC not your ARM device. Try ping with the address of the ARM device. For that, of course you should know the IP address for the ARM device, which I guess from your efforts so far, you might not know. If you have a direct ethernet line between your HOST pc and your ARM device and if the ARM device hopes to use DHCP, you might be in a predicament. If you know the IP Address of your ARM device, simply ping <address-of-arm-device> from your HOST PC. It might be easier to get started if you have a standard LAN with a dhcp server and a switch.

Comment: Sometimes there is a serial  (RS232) connector on such devices which shows you - if you connect a terminal program to it - the boot output, including the ethernet configuration it tries to accomplish.

Comment: @user2225104 that explains everything------the addresses in /etc/network/interfaces are the local addresses...
thanks, then. I think I've enough information to try things out

Answer (score 0):

With a 24 bit subnet mask, the .0 and .255 addresses are not usable for actual devices.  You might try setting your embedded linux to use .2 as its address and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do below way.

```
#eth0 down
#ifconfig eth0 192.168.6.14 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.6.6
#eth0 up
```

The IP address I have used is for an example you have to use the required IP for your server. In My case the Target IP is 192.168.6.14 nemask is 255.255.255.0 and gateway is 192.168.6.6.

Then it will start pinging.
Hope this helps.